# add and remove button in jsp to add and delete the fields before inserting into database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Facility Screen</title>
<script>
function loadxml()
{

    //pid=document.getElementById("pid");
input=document.getElementById("customer_id");

alert(input.value);
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();           
        }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            //alert("hi");
            // alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            var res=xmlhttp.responseText.split("+");
                s=document.getElementById("select");
                for(var j = 0; j < res.length-1; j++)
                    { 
            //      alert("hi");
                        var t = document.createElement("option");
                        t.value =res[j];
                        t.innerHTML =res[j] ;
                        s.appendChild(t);

        }  


            }


    }


    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/EMS/Facility_controller?cid="+input.value,true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}
</script>
<script>

function loadxml1()
{




alert("hi");
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();           
        }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {

             res=xmlhttp.responseText.split("+");
                s=document.getElementById("select1");
                for(var j = 0; j < res.length-1; j++)
                    { 
                        var t = document.createElement("option");
                        t.value =res[j];
                        t.innerHTML =res[j] ;
                        s.appendChild(t);

        }  


            }


    }


    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/EMS/Facilty_type",true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}




</script>
<script>
function loadxml2()
{
    alert("xml2");

var input=document.getElementById("select1");


    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();           
        }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {

             res=xmlhttp.responseText.split("+");
                s=document.getElementById("select2");
                for(var j = 0; j < res.length-1; j++)
                    { 
                        var t = document.createElement("option");
                        t.value =res[j];
                        t.innerHTML =res[j] ;
                        s.appendChild(t);

        }  


            }


    }


    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/EMS/vendor_id?facility="+input.value,true);
    xmlhttp.send();  
}




</script>
<script >

function loadxml3()
{

    facility=document.getElementById("select1");
    alert(facility.value);

    vendor_id=document.getElementById("select2");
    alert(vendor_id.value);
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();           
        }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {

        document.getElementById("myDiv").value=xmlhttp.responseText;


            }


    }


    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/EMS/Cost_controller?facility="+facility.value+"&vendor_id="+vendor_id.value,true);
    xmlhttp.send();  
}




</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" >
<table>
<tr>
<td>Customer id</td>
<td><input type="text" id="customer_id" name="customer_id" onblur="loadxml()"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
<table>
<tr><td>VENUE ID</td><td><select id="select" onchange="loadxml1()"></select></td></tr>
<tr><td>FACILITY</td><td><select id="select1" onchange="loadxml2()" ></select></td></tr>
<tr><td>VEDNOR ID</td><td><select id="select2" onchange="loadxml3()"></select></td></tr>
<tr><td>COST</td><td><input type="text" id="myDiv"></td></tr>
<tr><td>QUANTITY</td><td><input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity"></td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the front end of my event management system project upon which I am doing the facility_module on I am able to populate the combo box dynamically from the database using Ajax but I have to add the same fields facility vendor_id cost and quantity once more when I am pressing the add button and remove the fields when pressing remove button on pressing submit button all these values are to be added into the database .How to add the same fields again in jsp using jquery or Ajax??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons add/remove are missing in the html. I assume that you will have these buttons on the page to allow user to add/remove rows from the table. This example is well suited to make use of AngularJS. You can build your model based on response from Ajax and can then repeat over  tag to add more rows to the table.

If you are looking for a solution without AngularJS, then you can give an id to the first table row. Get the innerHTML of that table row using jquery id selector. Use the innerHTML to add another row to the table. Do not fire another ajax call to get the values.

Solution using AngularJS

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Facility Screen</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var TDataCtrl = function ($scope) {
            $scope.venues = [{name:'venue1',value:'venue1'},{name:'venue2', value:'venue2'}];
            $scope.facilities = [{name:'facility1',value:'facility1'},{name:'facility2',value:'facility2'}];
            $scope.vendors = [{name:'vendor1',value:'vendor1'},{name:'vendor2', value:'vendor2'}];
            $scope.tdata = [{'id': '0'}];
            $scope.addRow = function(){
                $scope.tdata[$scope.tdata.length]={'id':$scope.tdata.length};
            };
            $scope.removeRow = function(){
                $scope.tdata.pop();
            };
        };

    </script>

</head>
<body data-ng-app>
<form method="get">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Customer id</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="customer_id" name="customer_id"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
<div data-ng-controller="TDataCtrl">
<table >
    <tbody data-ng-repeat="thisrow in tdata">
    <tr>
        <td>VENUE ID</td>
        <td>
            <select id="select">
                <option ng-repeat="option in venues" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>FACILITY</td>
        <td>
            <select id="select1">
                <option ng-repeat="option in facilities" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.name}}</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>VEDNOR ID</td>
        <td>
            <select id="select2">
                <option ng-repeat="option in vendors" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>COST</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="myDiv"></td>
        <td>QUANTITY</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity"></td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Add" data-ng-click="addRow()"/>
<input type="button" value="Remove" data-ng-click="removeRow()"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HOW TO ADD SELECT ELEMENT BY USING ID CAN U PLEASE DEMONSTRATE HOW TO USE INNER HTML TO REPEAT THE TABLE ROW